# Tournament graph question(s)

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graph, tournament

Is a tournament graph the same thing as a directed complete graph? And, do all vertices in a tournament graph have the same number of edges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something obvious then the answer to both your questions is "yes"

A tournament graph is defined as a complete graph with a direction chosen for the edges.  Hence it is a directed complete graph.

[Wikipedia definition of a Tournament Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory))

and since a complete graph has an edge between each vertex, then every vertex has the same number of edges, and this doesn't change when a direction is chosen for the edge.

[Wikipedia definition of a Complete Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph)